# Intel XDK/Cordova onDeviceReady event does not fire

Tags: cordova, event-handling, intel-xdk

First I want to say that all the things work in the emulators, but when I build it and test it on a device they don't.

I wanted to set my orientation to landscape, so I followed the examples with:

```
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);               
function onDeviceReady(){
    intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation('landscape');
    intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();   
}
```

When I use it in "Test" mode, push the files on the server and then download the app from the cloud it works fine.

But when I build the app using Build-> Clicking Build for android from the "Cordova 3.X Hybrid Mobile App Platforms" menu, then download it and install it, it does not work.

You could say that I could build the app from the "Legacy Hybrid Mobile App Platforms" menu and then in the "Assets" menu to choose landscape. Yes that works, but I want also to use `hideStatusBar()` which also requires the `onDeviceReady` event to fire.

I'm testing it on Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1.2 and LG G2 with Android 4.4.2.

Also, I started a new project with a template and there are these lines:

```
// Listen to deviceready event which is fired when Cordova plugins are ready
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    // Call splashscreen API to hide the splash.
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
});
```

But they also don't work.

It seems like the `deviceReady` event does not fire at all. Any idea what could be the problem or suggestions for workarounds? I just want the app to be in landscape and the status bar to be hidden. I don't need anything else from the XDK.

PS: If requested, I can post the `index.html` and other code.

Comment: Did you make sure the device plugin was enabled?  Go to the projects pane and look at cordova plugins.

Comment: Yep it's on, but I decided to use Cocoonjs to wrap up the app. It works perfectly. I just couldn't find any logical solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was indeed in the enabling the plug- ins. It turned out I have to enable both "Device" plug- ins in "Included plug- ins menu" and also in the "Featured and Custom Cordova plug- ins". (right next to it).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can solve it.

```
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(intel){
            //your block code inside the onDeviceReady()
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    },200);
```

This code inside the interval will be called, in a 200ms interval, until the object 'intel' is defined.